# Service does not stay alive

Tags: android, service

I'm writting an application that listens to incoming SMS. So I wrote a service launching a BroadcastReceiver for that.
The service is started by my application, but when the latter is destroyed, my service does not seem to listen to anything. As the purpose of this service is to listen to incoming SMS, it has to be running "forever" (or restarted because of memory management).

Here is some code:

```
public class SmsService extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = SmsService.class.getSimpleName();
    public static boolean SMS_SERVICE_STARTED = false;
    private boolean mRegistered = false;
    public final static String SMS_PORT = "port";

    private SMSReceiver mSmsReceiver = null; // this is the BroadcastReceiver listening to SMS

    public SmsService() {
        super();
        Log.d(TAG, "SmsService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        SMS_SERVICE_STARTED = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        stopListenSms();
        SMS_SERVICE_STARTED = false;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");

        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(SMS_PORT)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "we got extra!");
            short port = intent.getShortExtra(SMS_PORT, (short) 0);
            startListenSms(port);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "no extra :(");
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void startListenSms(short port) {
        Log.d(TAG, "startListenSms on port " + port);

        mSmsReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
                "android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED");
        filter.addDataScheme("sms");
        String strPort = String.valueOf(port);
        filter.addDataAuthority("localhost", strPort);
        registerReceiver(mSmsReceiver, filter);
        mRegistered = true;
    }

    private void stopListenSms() {
        Log.d(TAG, "stopListenSms");
        if (mSmsReceiver != null) {
            if (mRegistered)
                unregisterReceiver(mSmsReceiver);
            mSmsReceiver = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I observed when its activity is destroyed, onStartCommand is called with a null Intent.
Do you have an idea why my service stops living when the activity is destroyed?
And how should I do to make it run "forever"?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need to run a service to listen to incoming SMS. Broadcast receiver itself serves the purpose, it will keep listening to the incoming message once you configured in the intent filter while registering the receivers. There are tons of examples Broadcast Receiver and SMS listening. Please go through those example and build your code efficiently

Comment: My BroadcastReceiver that listens to SMS already works. But if I'm not wrong, it cannot work if the activity which created it is destroyed. Typically, when I receive an SMS, I need to perform an action with it ; if the activity is dead, I cannot perform it.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand what you're talking about now: I have to describe my BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest, instead of doing it programmatically!

Answer (score 0):

A service has also a lifecycle and can be terminated by the system. You canot prevent this, although you can put your service into the foreground, which makes it harder for the system to terminate it. Nontheless, it is still possible; a service **cannot** run forever. Have a look at a service's lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle

What you need is a BroadcastReceiver that listens for the SMS intent (I don't know exactly which one it is). The BroadcastReceiver can register for certain intents (e.g., an incomming SMS) and is started when such an intent is sent by the system. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: I don't want to run it in foreground, because I don't want any notification icon in the status bar.